# Is it possible to add attributes to the generated members of an ExpandoObject instance?

Tags: .net, propertygrid, custom-attributes, expando, expandoobject

I'm trying to use an ExpandoObject as the SelectedObject of a PropertyGrid. I know how to add the properties I want to the ExpandoObject:

```
public dynamic MakePropertyObject()
{
    dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
    var dictionary = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;
    foreach(MyClass m in PropertiesINeedToAdd)
        dictionary[m.Name] = m.Value;
    return expando;
}
```

This code's working fine- the debugger shows the names and values of `expando`'s properties as expected.

However, none of the generated properties is showing up in the PropertyGrid when I set the return value of `MakePropertyObject()` to its `SelectedObject` property. I assume (perhaps falsely) that this is because the `ExpandoObject`'s properties don't have any `DisplayNameAttribute`, `DescriptionAttribute`, or any of the other attributes used to control how properties are displayed in a `PropertyGrid`.

I've done some reading and some Googling, and I can't figure out if there's a way to decorate the generated properties of an `ExpandoObject` with custom attributes. Does anyone know how this can be done, or of a better way to show an `ExpandoObject` in a `PropertyGrid`?

**SOLUTION:**

The answer provided by @Stephen Cleary was correct and helpful (thanks, Stephen). For others with the same problem, implementing `ICustomTypeDescriptor` worked perfectly for me.

As a side note, ***the object that implements `ICustomTypeDescriptor` provides the property and event descriptors for itself, not for another object***. I thought the descriptor and the described were supposed to be linked by an attribute or something at first- it seemed confusing and redundant to me that an object should describe its own type, but that's indeed how `PropertyGrid`s use the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is actually that reflection doesn't work as expected on dynamic types.

`PropertyGrid` uses reflection to examine its object's properties, and `ExpandoObject` doesn't have any (static) properties.

You can implement [`ICustomTypeDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx) to "hijack" the reflection and query the (dynamic) properties of the `ExpandoObject`. The code for `DynamicTypeDescriptorWrapper` in [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/09/17/fun-with-c-4-0-s-dynamic.aspx) would be a good starting point.