# Adding attributes to an ExpandObject member var?

Tags: c#

I have found this thread that talks a bit about it: [Is it possible to add attributes to the generated members of an ExpandoObject instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766777/is-it-possible-to-add-attributes-to-the-generated-members-of-an-expandoobject-in)

but it seems to just focus on the powergrid.

I have spent about 1 hour looking for this on google without any luck either. Could anyone at least confirm if it can be done?.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an interface and add the Attribute to the interface.

Than use Improptu: http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/

```
IMyInterface instance = Impromptu.ActLike<IMyInferface>(myexpando);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really apreciate it, but would like to stick to .net built-in features if it is possible. Could it be done without using external libs?

Comment: The question is, what do you want to achive? A custom TypeDescriptor would be a way. Another solution is to write a wrapper class around your expando object.

Comment: I'm using an ORM that maps C# classes to a database tables. I want to be able to generate this dynamically. The problem is hat the ORM uses the member vars decoration to add meta information like if it is a primarykey, unique, etc... So, I can now create a ExpandoObject and populate it with the needed members but can't add the custom attributes (decoration) to let the ORM work as expected when reqeusting a query, etc...